# Phalcon install failed

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to install phalcon, so followed this step:

1. I download the phalcon_x64_vc15_php7.4_nts.zip.zip, from here(https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v5.0.0-alpha.2)
   [image]
2. I go to this pages(https://pecl.php.net/package/psr/1.1.0/windows) to download 7.3 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64
3. put **php_phalcon.dll、php_psr.dll、php_psr.pdb** inside php\ext
4. and then I modify the php.ini with this

```
extension=php_psr.dll 
extension=php_phalcon.dll
```

5. Phalcon is not install successfully, the error shows PHP Warning:  **PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_psr.dll'、Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_phalcon.dll'**
   [image]
6. This is my PHP version.

[image]
Can someone help me to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to install phalcon for PHP 7.4 (it's in the file name: `phalcon_x64_vc15_php7.4_nts`) on PHP 7.3? Try it on PHP 7.4 instead. Also make sure it's trying to load it from the correct path (seeing that the ini file is in `C:\cos\nginx-1.21.0\php` while it tries to load the dll from `C:\ext\php`)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your answer, now I have installed the PHP 7.3 from here(https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v4.1.2) choose this one(phalcon_x64_vc15_php7.3_4.1.2+5275_nts.zip
), and use extension_dir to the correct path(ex: extension_dir="C:\cos\nginx-1.21.0\php\ext\php_phalcon.dll"), the error message disappeared, but when I use php -m, I still can't find phalcon.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson When I changed to this (extension="C:\cos\nginx-1.21.0\php\ext\php_phalcon.dll"), it works, when I use php -m, phalcon was showing up. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to download phalcon v5.0.0-alpha.2 which is compatible with php version 7.4 (minimum). Try either upgrading to PHP 7.4 or try downgrading your phalcon version.

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v4.1.2

Here you can download and use V4.1.2 which supports PHP version 7.3 and 7.4